# OUT OF BREATH v.s BREATHLESS

Tags: differences

What is the difference between 'out of breath' and 'breathless'? I have read the dictionary carefully. I saw an example is that:" We were out of breath after only five minutes''. And 'out of breath' is used with the meaning ' having the difficulty breathing after exercise'. I Wonder if we can use 'breathless' instead of ' out of breath' in that case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of breath means just that, that you are physically out of breath.

Breathless is generally used in other phrasing, such as "breathless with anticipation" or a similar "breathtaking candor." Usually it's used metaphorically to say that something so exceptional has happened that it figuratively took your breath away. Out of breath means you're literally out of breath.

If you are trying to say you are literally physically out of breath from exercise, I think it would be more elegant to use out of breath instead of breathless.

Comment: Very happy to help! :)